# Map only displays correctly on window size change

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm using mapbox to create this map, but when the map is initialised, it offsets the lat and long and blanks out most of the map (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PZJ2.png)). When the window is resized, it displays the map correctly (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XmVY.png)).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var homeLatitude = 50.351;
var homeLongitude = -3.576;
var initialZoom = 15;
var mapInitialised = 0;

// Initialise map
var map = mapInit(mapInitialised, homeLatitude, homeLongitude, initialZoom);
});

function mapInit(mapInitialised, homeLatitude, homeLongitude, initialZoom) {
// initialise map
if ( mapInitialised===0 ) {
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'map.sdfwe45ht')
        .setView([homeLatitude, homeLongitude], initialZoom);
    mapInitialised = 1;
}
return map; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your map with `$(window).load(function() {})`, not `document.ready`: document.ready runs before the contents of your page have correctly sized themselves.